# sqlite - how do I write a query to receive an additional column containing a selection of data from another table in every cell

Tags: sqlite

Assume I have two tables, e.g.:

```
table_1:
+----+-------+------------+--
| id | name  | table_2_id | ... 
+----+-------+------------+--
| 1  | test1 | 2          | ...   
| 2  | test2 | 1          | ...
| 3  | test3 | 1          | ...
...
```

and

```
table_2:
+----+------+--
| id | name | ... 
+----+------+--
| 1  | xxx  | ...   
| 2  | yyy  | ...
| 3  | zzz  | ...
...
```

Now I want to select everything from `table_2` and add another column containing in every cell a collection of all names from `table_1` where `table_2_id` corresponds with the current `id` from `table_2`:

```
output:
+----+------+-----+--------------+
| id | name | ... | link         |
+----+------+-----+--------------+
| 1  | xxx  | ... | test2, test3 |
| 2  | yyy  | ... | test1        |
| 3  | zzz  | ... | %            |
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() + GROUP BY can accomplish this.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve], i.e. a `.dump` from SQLite commandline tool for a suitably tailored toy database, which contains the tables you have shown. Then show your own attempts. Have you managed to get the information you want, just in a different layout? I.e. show your queries, the output you manage to produce and explain what you do not like about it.

Comment: @Alex K.: thanks for your hint

Comment: @Yunnosch: I'll do so next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub).
To combine values from multiple rows, use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT id,
       name, 
       (SELECT group_concat(name)
        FROM table_1
        WHERE table_2_id = table_2.id
       ) AS link
FROM table_2;
```